# Localization particular language in swift

Tags: swift, localization

I work with localization and have a question:
**I need this:** 
if language = english -> use this func, else use this func
I don't really understand how I can clarify this particular language

Comment: Use the following with the String contains property.  let lan = NSLocale.preferredLanguages[0] as String

Comment: @ElTomato can you right me an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**An option could be for you to have a localised key in both your translations:**

Localizable.string (English) `current_language = "en"`

Localizable.string (Russian) `current_language = "ru"`

And then

```
let currentLanguage = NSLocalizedString("current_language", comment: "")
if currentLanguage == "en" {
   englishFunction()
} else {
   russianFunction()
}
```

**2) 2nd option could be to check Device language:**

```
let deviceLanguage = Locale.current.languageCode
```

**3) 3rd option could be to check User preferred language:**

```
let userPreferredLanguage = Locale.preferredLanguages[0]
```

To understand the difference between App Language and Device Language think of it as in this example: when your app develeopment language is EN and your device is set with IT (italian) language, and you have no localization for IT then: `deviceLanguage = en`, `userPreferredLanguage = it`

Your `app development language` is the default fallback language that will be used as localization in case you have no support language for the user preferences language, the `default/fallback language` you can find in your `.plist` file under this key: `CFBundleDevelopmentRegion`